# cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, export, text-files

This is my code:

```
string path = @"c:\temp\mytext.txt";
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var firstValue = line.Split(new string[] { "   " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
    Console.WriteLine(firstValue);

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\WriteLines.txt", firstValue);
}
```

I want to export my first value to a text file. How i can export it?

I get this error:

> Cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

at this line

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\WriteLines.txt", firstValue);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes a *sequence* of strings - you've only got a *single* string.

If you only want your file to contain that single string, just use [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\WriteLines.txt", firstValue);
```

However, given that you've got this *in a loop* it's going to keep replacing the contents of the file with the first part of each line of the input file.

If you're trying to get the first part of *each* line of your input file into your output file, you'd be better off with:

```
var query = File.ReadLines(inputFile)
                .Select(line => line.Split(new string[] { "   " },
                                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);
File.WriteAllLines(outputFile, query);
```

---

Note that with a `using` directive of

```
using System.IO;
```

you don't need to fully-qualify everything, so your code will be much clearer.

Comment: @user1477332: Well do you have anything in your *input* file? (See my edit, too...)